# jQuery UI Dialog top spacing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I need a dialog to always have 100px gap between the top of the window and the top of the dialog. However, if the dialog is taller than the window, it will always sit flush with the top of the window (`top` is 0px).

Setting a `top`, `margin-top`, and `padding-top` to the dialog with CSS doesn't help, as it takes these values into account when working out the top value, and still positions it flush with the top of the window (i.e. adding `margin-top: 100px` means it ends up being positioned with `top: -100px`). Using the built in option, such as `'position': ['center', 100]`, doesn't work once the dialog is taller than the window.

I'd also rather avoid having to manually adjust the position after every initialisation if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to need to overwrite the "using" part of the position configuration, see this: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/9268634b800ae2148bf088cd229a3bafe2534c7c/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js#L60-L66

Comment: Thank you. That didn't quite work but I just put in the offset I wanted manually and it worked.

`position: {
 using: function( pos ) {
  var topOffset = $( this ).css( pos ).offset().top;
  if ( topOffset < 0 ) {
   $( this ).css( "top", 50 );
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Mhh, you should probably add offset AND overwrite using as this could reset the top position on small screens.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this with `open` event options like so:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    open : function() {
        if ($(this).closest('.ui-dialog').offset().top < 40) {
            $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').css({'top':'40px'});
        }
    }
});
```